# How to add scroll bar in CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, window

I would like to add scroll bar in this terminal like window in CSS if the text overflow. I tried overflow-y:scroll but it didn't work.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-osx-terminal

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar was hidden out of view. If you add

```css
box-sizing:border-box;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

to the code for `#body`, it will work as planned.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pbhmi7ux

Comment: It increases the window size. I am expecting a scroll bar with the same window size.

Comment: Hm? The width depends on the window width.

Comment: Do I need to care about the width? I want only the vertical scroll bar. Height and width should not change.

Comment: I am new to CSS/HTML. could you give some suggestion for this?